# ​No Category: help Shows this message. Type !help command for more info on a command. You can also type !help category for more info on a category

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord.py

I changed over from the regular discord.py to the rewrite version, and I used to have a custom !help command that I made.

Now, whenever I post !help, it brings this up along with the coded-in help message:

```
​No Category:
help Shows this message.   

Type !help command for more info on a command.
You can also type !help category for more info on a category.
```

Any Ideas on how to remove this? I checked the internet, but it only seems to have people just asking how to change the descriptions and category name of the !help command.

Comment: Afak, you can't define a custom help command without removing the pre existing help command. You should be getting an error upon running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the built-in help command using [`Bot.remove_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command).  Something like

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot('!')
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `help_command` keyword argument to `None` in `commands.Bot()`, like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import comands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", help_command=None)
```